# Does convergence of power series on radius of convergence imply absolute convergence?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Let $R$ be radius of convergence of power seires $\displaystyle\sum_{k}a_kz^k$.

If the power series converges for all $|z|=R$, can we say that it converges absolutely on the radius of convergence?

I tried to show that ${a_k}=\frac{e^{ik^2q}}{k}$ where $q$ is an irrational, serves as a counter example. In this case, $R=1$, and the series diverges absolutely for $|z|=1$. I wanted to choose summation by part to conclude its convergence but it does not seem to work.

Comment: It converges absolutely in the interior of the interval, it may or may not converge absolutely at the boundary points.  In fact it may or may not converge at all at the boundary points.

Comment: [The answer is no](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/110345/does-a-power-series-converging-everywhere-on-its-circle-of-convergence-define-a), convergence everywhere on the boundary circle doesn't imply absolute convergence, for absolute convergence would imply continuity.

Comment: @DanielFischer   Can you tell me whose continuity does absolute convergence imply? Thanks

Comment: If a power series $\sum c_n z^n$ is absolutely convergent on a circle $\lvert z\rvert = R$, that implies that the sum of the power series is a continuous function on the closed disk $\lvert z\rvert \leqslant R$, for then the convergence is uniform on the closed disk. By contrapositive, if the series converges on the whole boundary circle, but the sum function is not continuous at some point of the boundary circle [we know it's continuous on the open disk], it follows that the convergence cannot be uniform, and hence not absolute on the boundary.

Comment: @DanielFischer   Now I see absolute convergence imply continuity of the limit function. But I still do not know why convergence on the disk does not imply absolute convergence.

Comment: Sierpiński has, according to the linked MO thread, constructed a power series converging on the closed unit disk, whose limit function is unbounded, and hence not continuous. So this power series cannot be absolutely convergent for $\lvert z\rvert = 1$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Can you give me a link of his construction? Thanks!